# "postion:sticky" stops working after setting "display:block" on tr&&tbody

Tags: html, sass, html-table, css-position

First of all excuse me for possibile mistakes, English is not my mother tongue but I hope to be clear enough...

So I've this problem: I need to style a table with first column and row fixed **WITHOUT scripts**. I've searched a lot and found really lots of suggestions here on SO, which led me to fix both the first row and column.

To do so I've used the same table, but I've implemented the various solutions 
separately (on two different .sass files).

This is the HTML of the table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th id="1" class="dayColumn">Lunedì</th>
            <th id="2" class="dayColumn">Martedì</th>
            <th id="3" class="dayColumn">Mercoledì</th>
            <th id="4" class="dayColumn">Giovedì</th>
            <th id="5" class="dayColumn">Venerdì</th>
            <th id="6" class="dayColumn">Sabato</th>
            <th id="7" class="dayColumn">Domenica</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="hourNumber">**0**</td>
            <td class="busy"></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class="busy"></td>
        </tr>
        //the same thing over and over until 
        <tr>
            <td class="hourNumber">**24**</td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class=""></td>
        </tr>
        //don't mind the fact that I have 25 hours
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To freeze the first ROW I've used this SASS, which worked fine:

```
table
    thead
        tr
            display: block

        .dayColumn
            height: 35px
            min-width: 358px

        .hourNumber
            min-width: 30px

    tbody
        display: block
        overflow: auto
        height: 450px

        td
            min-width: 367px
```

To freeze the first COLUMN I've used this SASS:

```
table
    tbody
        tr
            text-align: center

            td
                min-width: 300px

        .hourNumber
            min-width: 30px
            position: sticky
            left: 0px
            border: #4d4d4d

        .dayColumn
            min-width: 358px
```

... which also worked correctly.

The problem is: when I combine the two solutions, the sticky solution for the first column stops working... Can anyone help me understand why this does happen?

NOTE: if you're not familiar with SASS use this site to convert it to CSS3: https://www.sassmeister.com/

NOTE2: I've also tried to use the fixed solution applied to the class .hourNumber AND to the td:nth-child(1) but I've got problems with it and ragequitted :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: sticky` is well known to not work properly on certain parts of a table for technical reasons. Unfortunately you'll have to resort to a JS solution or none at all.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it's not possibile then to use and alternative solution to freeze the first ROW without touching the display property? I've tried with sticky to freeze it too but without success (read here on SO of the problems). Unfortunately I can't use scripts because the assignments I got specifies I need to use only CSS/SCSS/SASS. Is my teacher really that a****le? D:

Comment: It's certainly possible if you're allowed to change the HTML structure? In theory, you could change the display type of all the table elements, though that's quite the hack.

Comment: Uhm, I'll see what I can do but I think the table is generated using ReactJS and I don't really know it. I'll dig it tomorrow because after hours of tries I need some rest. Thanks for now ^^

Comment: I'm marking this as solution because it seems there isn't any other possibile solution. Thanks :>